# Thunderbird mail-Outlook 11.10

Tags: 11.10, thunderbird, email

I want to use Thunderbird mail, but can I use my outlook e-mail?

It's not that urgent, but I want to use it.

Comment: What do you mean by `can I use my outlook e-mail?` Do you mean you want to use the outlook client? or do you mean you want the email you have on outlook, configured on Thunderbird?

Comment: Do you mean **Hotmail**, re-branded **Outlook.com**? Do you want your old Outlook mailbox (and archive) transferred? ***Please clarify.***

Comment: I mean the new outlook. Don't worry though, as i've sorted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook is a software which runs on Windows only, not Linux. So if you want to use Outlook on Ubuntu, you will have to use a Windows emulator like WINE to make Outlook run on your Linux.